# Properties file gets unloaded

Tags: java, struts2, internationalization

I have a Struts 2 web application running on `Tomcat 7` on Windows Server 2008 (only Tomcat, no Apache or IIS). The texts in the application are stored in .properties files and are managed by Struts 2 I18N Interceptor. In the JSPs I use `<s:text name="menu.help" />` tags.
Some times (twice in the last month), the application loses the references to the properties files, as they were unloaded, and it starts to show the keys instead. For example for English it always shows "Help", but when I get this issue it starts showing "menu.help". I have to restart the application for it to work normally again.
I looked for related errors in the logs, but could not find anything related to I18n or properties. I also looked for `OutOfMemoryError`, but could not find any either.
Do you know what could be the problem? Can you think on any way I can troubleshoot it?
Thanks

**Edit:**
This is the relevant part of my struts.xml:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="resources" />
    ...
```

And the properties files `(resources_en.properties, resources_es.properties, ...)` are located in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory.

Comment: You might want to post on the Struts User mailing list for this one. I suspect something is being garbage collected, but not sure what it'd be.

Comment: What did you try to troubleshoot it? Did you try to switching locale manually?

Comment: @RomanC I have the possibility within the application to switch languages, and it didn't work for any language until I restarted the application.

Comment: @RomanC When I switched languages I still got the keys instead of the text, for any language. When I restarted the application it started working again, showing the correct texts for the selected language.

Comment: Where do you have keys? What is in your struts.xml?

Comment: Really weird... are you in a Clustered environment ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios No, a stand-alone Tomcat 7 installation with only one application.

Comment: Can you check if you have more than one resources_en file in your classpath? Maybe you have multiple ones and the application finds the incomplete one from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a default properties: resources.properties

Surelly this times you get keys instead of translations is because default locale is not set.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the memory problem, I suggest you do below:

1. Minimize the size of property file, see if this solves the issue. So first minimize the size, make a load test and see the result.
2. Split it to different property files to see if this happens to all of them or just some of them

This is my personal experience:

Sometimes the JVM (by mistake) garbage collect an object when it is not used a while. I have the same issue with JDK 4 and oracle application server 9i. The JVM garbage collected the database connection when the site load dropped. So, develop a small jsp page (test.jsp), add `<s:text name="menu.help" />` to it. Then, write a small application which request this page every 1min.